# How to create dates in another timezone, in browser Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

I have a client side web application where the user must create Dates for timezones other then their own, and I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

Using Moment Timezone, I know how I can *change* a time into another timezone. That is, convert `Nov 18 2013 11:00:00 GMT-0500` to `Nov 19 2013 03:00:00 GMT+1100`. These still represent the same absolute time, but just with a different 'view'.

What I need to do is convert, respecting daylight savings, `Nov 18 2013 11:00:00 America/Toronto"` to `Nov 18 2013 11:00:00 Australia/Sydney` (which are different absolute times).

So far the only way I can come up with is to create a `Date`, serialize it to string, and then parse it with Moment Timezone, something like:

```
localEvent = new Date(2015, 03, 10, 18, 30)
eventStr = localEvent.toString().split('GMT')[0]
# eventStr = 'Fri Apr 10 2015 18:30:00'
event = moment.tz(eventStr, 'Australia/Sydney')
```

So now this code will create the exact same point in time regardless of which timezone the browser is operating in.

But this feels very hacky, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you know the hour differential are do you need to look that up?

Comment: @WillReese I need to look that up because the hour differential can change. Due to daylight savings, in the time between when the hour differential was saved, and the Date time created, the offset may have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that better:

```
var zone = moment().tz('Australia/Sydney');

var c = moment(new Date(2015, 03, 10, 18, 30));
c.utcOffset(zone.utcOffset(), true);
                             // ^--- this flag keeps the same time
                             //      while shifts a timezone

console.log(c.format());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8m6rdzqj/

How I found it: I just went through the moment and moment-timezone source: https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/master/moment-timezone.js#L347